# subscribe 6 ladybug_images to ROS

Tags: c++, publish-subscribe, ros

I am trying to send 6 images from Ladybug camera (https://www.ptgrey.com/ladybug5-360-degree-usb3-spherical-camera-systems) to ROS.

and when ROS received those images he used a 3D mesh stitching generator which generates a panorama image in sphere format. to sum up, I want to subscribe the stitching images program to get a panorama in real time.

the image format are in bmp. 
I found a tutorial about subscribing but I don t know how to use it

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>

void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
 try
{
cv::imshow("view", cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, "bgr8")->image);
}
catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
{
ROS_ERROR("Could not convert from '%s' to 'bgr8'.", msg->encoding.c_str());
 }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   ros::init(argc, argv, "image_listener");
   ros::NodeHandle nh;
   cv::namedWindow("view");
   cv::startWindowThread();
   image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
   image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("camera/image", 1,   imageCallback);
   ros::spin();
   cv::destroyWindow("view");
    }
```

I would like that you clarify to me the method to realize that.

I hope i am clear, thank you in advance